# Is it possible to exclude .cs file from PDB file?

Tags: c#, .net, pdb-files

I was compiling Release build of my application, and it placed PDB file near executable, which is fine for me, because it will provide more detailed stacktrace when my app might crash (like `.cs` files and corresponding lines there), and also allows you to open your app through decompiled (like dotPeek) and see in which `.cs` file was corresponding class. But I was wandering, is it possible to exclude specific .cs files from adding into PDB file?

For example, I have two `.cs` files:

- Main.cs
- .. other `.cs` files
- Internal.cs

Is it possible to generate PDB file including `Main.cs` and other `.cs` files, but exclude `Internal.cs` file?

Thanks.

Comment: A PDB contains debug symbols that point to source code, not the files themselves. Why are you asking this?

Comment: I think that what OP want is to excleude information about classes when it came from some files ...

Comment: A Release build isn't a published application. You don't have to distribute the PDB file. *You* want the full file though, precisely because *you* want to be able to debug any problems.

Comment: Well, when I tried to open my app through dotPeek (while PDB file was near EXE) it quickly found out in which file was selected class. But when I deleted PDB file, dotPeek decompiled assembly and dotPeek couldn't figure out in what file selected class was. That's why I asking this

Comment: You may move those classes to another assembly/library and not distribute pdb for it

Comment: Yea, I thought about moving those classes to another assembly, but it doesn't really matter for my current project, this question is more for my curiosity

Comment: @craftersmine you repeated the question in the comment. You still haven't explained *why* you want to give users a PDB file they'll never use in the first place, but exclude some information. dotPeek doesn't need a PDB to decompile your code anyway. Don't give the PDB away in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, I know that dotPeek doesn't need a PDB to decompile it, it if there is a PDB, it will not decompile, rather use PDB to get classes in assembly, which reveals whole `.cs` file with all classes in it, rather separating those classes as classes. For example if I have "obfuscated" `.cs` file, and decompile assembly using dotPeek with PDB alongside, then whole "obfuscated" `.cs` file will become one file, while without PDB file, every class opens in other tabs without debug information

Comment: Not exactly. But you still haven't explained why you want to give away a PDB at all. It's typically 10 times bigger than the application itself so people never include it in installers or deployments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question is probably about hiding as much as possible of debug information related to specific `.cs` files while maintaining enough debug information in production. Like you kind of questioned your question, to also make PDB file smaller while maintaining quite enough debug information.

Comment: And that's why it makes no sense. It's *YOUR* PDB file, just as it's YOUR source file. Why not delete the .cs file so it can't "leak" ? That's what you're saying. The generated PDB is the same as your .cs file, or the contents of the `obj` directory

Comment: Maybe because if I delete `.cs` file, my app will not compile due to missing class?

Comment: The pdb file is in the bin debug folder.  You can add instead the dll from the release folder instead.

Comment: Don't give away the PDB then. If you do want to give a stripped PDB to clients, you'll have to use tools like [PDBCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/pdbcopy) from the Windows Debuggint Tools or [binplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/public-symbols-and-private-symbols) from the Windows Driver Development Kit to strip private symbols out of the PDB. PDBCopy can remove selected public symbols too

Comment: Okay, so it is possible to exclude some symbols from PDB, thanks